# SQLSRV not working when apache service is installed

Tags: apache, sqlsrv

Hellow! I use xampp-win32-5.6.32-0-VC11 on windows server 2016! As DB I use MSSQL 2016. Everything works fine, my connection to MSSQL establishes and script runs as charm but... ONLY WHEN I TRY TO INSTALL APACHE AS A SERVICE (IT INTALLS FINE) WHEN TRY TO CONNECT TO DB I HAD - ERROR:

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 124

I don't know what to do! Tryed reinstall xampp even different versions, moved pdo drivers for apache, use diffecent connection strings in database_config.php!
Anyone? may be had the same issue... Please help

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, finally! In database.php must be set username, I tried to connect automit true. When created user in MSSQL and set it in database.php it works!